# Metatag won't work for homepage?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

The [Metatag Module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) inputs (Such as Description, Abstract, ETC, and that includes Page Title) won't trigger on the home page.

I already read in a forum thread that didn't give an in-program solution. I assume it's a solved problem, because it affects almost any site.

How can one solve it?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://drupal.org/node/1848184#comment-6801690

> Check if you have the code for the main content on the homepage .tpl file:
>
> `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`